# Centos 7x with 3.16 kernel

Tags: centos, kernel, veeam

How do I get a 3.16 kernel? Veeam agent is not letting me backup btrfs with the 3.10, I grabbed 4.4 LT and system won't boot so scrapped that

Comment: Google search on `how to upgrade centos 7 kernel` gives tutorials by [HowtoForge](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-kernel-in-centos-7-server/), [Linux Hint](https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-centos-7/) and many more. Is there a good reason to write a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I'd get ahold of Veeam support and ask them why their agent doesn't work with a modern distro. If they support CentOS (as they should) then they need to fix their agent.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a kernel more recent than what ships with CentOS, you can either build your own or you can grab some kernel packages from one of the 3rd party repositories, e.g.

ElRepo:
https://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-ml

My own repository (4.9.x series):
http://mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.redsleeve.org/pub/misc/kernel/x86_64/RPMS/